# "hasInjectionContext" is not exported by "node_modules/vue-demi/lib/index.mjs", imported by "node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs"

Tags: javascript, npm, vuejs3, typescript-typings, pinia

When I start my programe,console print "hasInjectionContext" is not exported by "node_modules/vue-demi/lib/index.mjs", imported by "node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs".
at ../node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs:6:9.

I try to remove node_module and change pinia version to 2.0.36.But it doesn't work. How should I change? By the way , I stickUp Another node_module which pinia version is 2.0.36 also doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solve this problem by changing vue version to ^3.3.0.Seeing it is working properly now after changing version.
you can try this solution.

```
{
 "pinia": "^2.1.3",
 "sass": "^1.60.0",
 "sass-loader": "^13.2.2",
 "vue": "^3.3.0",
 "vue-cookies": "^1.8.3",
}
```

Comment: thankyou, I find the problem is caused by pinia version can not match vue version. pinia 2.1 need vue>=3.3.0. So I lock the pinia version also changed this problem

Comment: is there a way to properly update vue without any issues? i have 3.2 version and i'm using vite (which i don't even know which difference it makes exactly...makes you work with single file components?). so: project folder, console, i tried to update vue-cli to latest, it seems it's useless, so i try to update vue latest..it asks me to overwrite existing files (also .vue files i suppose, overwriting all existing code)...first impression, i find ridiculous i'm struggling so much for some vue update JUST to use pinia JUST to have a global state...so i'm asking for advice since i need pinia...